# Prove or Disprove: If $a_n$ was positive and its limit is positive then the limit of the $\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ is $1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $a_n$ was positive and its limit is positive then the limit of the $\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ is $1$. I think it has to do with multiplication to start here,but I couldnt figure it out.

Comment: Is $a_n$ a sequence or a series?

Comment: it is a positive sequence

Comment: Surely you meant $a_n$  is a positive sequence.

Comment: sorry for my English

Comment: by continuity of root of n and  because f(1)=1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a_n \to a >0$, then $\log a_n \to \log a$ by continuity of log (and $\log a$ is finite). Also, $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$, so $\frac{1}{n} \log a_n \to (0) \log a = 0$. By continuity of exponentiation, we have $(a_n)^{1/n} = e^{\frac{1}{n} \log a_n } \to e^0 = 1$, as desired.

Comment: thx.But I never saw the rule that log(n)---->log(a) but I understand it now.Thanks man!!

Comment: You ned to prove the continuity of the log.

Answer (score -2):

Here is an approach. Assuming $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n = L>0 $ and recalling the fact

> $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} (a_n)^{1/n} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{L}{L} = 1.$$

Comment: You need to prove the first equality.

Comment: @Batman: I am using a well known result and whoever is interested in its proof they can find it in the calculus and analysis books!

Comment: @Batman: Leave the OP take his time to read and understand the answer since it is directed to him! By the way I do not have much time.

Comment: Would you care explaining what's the downvote for?

Comment: Batmans answers is a lot understandable and short.I tried the same you tried but it didnt work out for me but anyway thx for the attempt.Any piece of help is appreciated

Comment: @Batman: Can you not see that it is a typo!

Comment: @shadihelf: It worked here!

Comment: where do you mean?